# Products not display in category page Elastic search

Tags: magento2, categories

I have configure multi store in my project, now i have assign some product to category but product is not displaying in front side. I have check product status, visibility and stock option all thing are fine but not display to front side.

In admin category edit page i am getting following message.
https://prnt.sc/ko3ion

I am using Elastic search.

anyone have idea about this ?

Answer (score 1):

I have Same issues Phase own my site After Elastic search Install You Configure  Elastic search service Own your Magento.
=> Store =>Configuration => Catalog => Catalog Search => And Search Engine By default "MySQL" You seated Elasticsearch
=> after set configuration Need to reindex

```
   php bin/magento index:reindex
   php bin/magento cache:flush
```

If after this step perform can't any error getting let me know.